# Translating Google Chrome Extension HTML Form

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Google Chrome extension with a HTML form in it that goes as follows

```
    <form action="http://www.geocaching.com/track/details.aspx?tracker=" method="get" class="f" target="_blank">
        <input type="search" name="tracker" placeholder="Tracking Number" maxlength="10"/>
        <input type="submit" class="btn search-submit" value="Search"> 
    </form>
```

I need to translate the `placeholder` and `value` tags within the form but I can't figure out how to translate items that are in a HTML tag. I have successfully translated plain text elsewhere in the HTML file using JavaScript `chrome.i18n.getMessage("name")`, but I don't know how to apply that to the HTML form.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setattribute function can be used for changing attribute value.

var element = document.getElementByName("tracker"); 
element.setAttribute("placeholder", "attributeValue");

var element = document.getElementsByClassName("btn search-submit"); 
element.value("attributeValue");

Comment: In the Chrome Debug Console it displays the error: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'setAttribute'

Comment: I would like it to automatically translate using the `chrome.i18n.getMessage("name")` method.